# Searching for records on one exact day

Tags: c#, datetime

In UI I have two `date picker` fields that user can select **start and end date** of his search. ( No time value entry, just date part) So for example he can enter the same date for both start and end of his criteria if he wants to only see the records for that one specific date.

Now in SQL Server those columns are stored as DateTime fileds with values like

```
'2013-04-04 10:48:02.830'
```

So because it keeps the time part in SQL Server too, then my searches return no result when the start and end date is the same in C# part.
How can I fix this on C# side? ( I am assuming there is a use case for the time part that we keep in SQL Server in some other part of the application so don't want to mess with back-end section).

**So:** SQL Server has values like `'2013-04-04 10:48:02.830'`
C# is passing values like `{11/26/2011 12:00:00 AM}`
And when the start and end date are the same, we get no results.

Comment: Why not just say `WHERE DbValueField >= 'StartDate 00:00:00' AND <= 'EndDate 23:59:59'`? Pseudo code before you ask! That will work if Start and End date is the same day too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have code on the back end that go to SQL Server for you, instead of having a UI that is data bound:

You simply take the two values you get from the UI and modify them as needed:

```
DateTime from = originalFromDate.Date;
DateTime to = originalToDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

and now if you search for anything that is between from and to, you'll find your records:

(in case of LINQ:)

```
var query = queryUntilNow.Where(x => x.Date >= from && x.Date <= to);
```

Comment: oh one ore question too: in my case I had to add the AddDay(1) part to the "StartDate" section to make it work, If I add it to the "EndDate" section the query still won't return results. Any idea on that weird thing?  Thanks

Comment: You are creating a time range -- that is, midnight on the first date and almost midnight on the day AFTER the second date (1 second earlier) -- say, 01/01/2013 at 00:00:00 until 02/01/2013 23:59:59. So any timestamp in this range is effectively in the from/to range.

Comment: @DevWannaBe: Adding a day to the start date cannot possibly be right, can it? If you get data back, it will not contain records from the start date itself...

Comment: Yes sorry my bad, I totally understood your solution and it works.

Comment: Why do the `AddSeconds(-1)` just make the range non inclusive. Drop the `AddSeconds` and just do `.Where(x => x.Date >= from && x.Date < to);` (note the `<` instead of `<=`). Doing it your way will make a time of `23:59:59.1` (Sql server can store fractional seconds) will show up on the wrong day.